# Is there a one-line way to write this same code but using some type of mutable map in Java 8?

Tags: java, hashmap, maps, immutability, mutable

```
  private Map<String,Object> contactQuestion = ImmutableMap.of("pageForm","contactInfo", "questionList",Arrays.asList(ImmutableMap.of("active",false)));
```

I'm defining this variable at the class level in a JUnit test, but I've realized I need the maps to be mutable. I wrote the code initially using the ImmutableMap class because it offered this convenient way of building the map in-line. I've found that in my tests I actually need to mutate these maps. I tried to use a HashMap but HashMap doesn't seem to have any function similar to ImmutableMap's `of()`. Is there some clever alternative here?

Thanks for any advice

Comment: How about `new HashMap(ImmutableMap.of(...))` ?

Comment: Why is this not a `class Question`?

Comment: @khelwood that worked, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not certain about `ImmutableMap.of` but since JDK 9

```
  private Map<String,Object> contactQuestion = new HashMap<> 
     (Map.of("pageForm","contactInfo", 
          "questionList",Arrays.asList(Map.of("active",false))));
```

For each `Map.of` you would need to pass that to a `Map` implementation if you want them all to be mutable.

Comment: Thanks, yeah wrapping it in a new HashMap<>() worked. Kinda messy, but it works.